# Which one is right?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, transitivity

Which one is right:

> I would love to spend it rather than preserving.
>
> I would love to spend it rather than  preserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like either one. I think this is better:

> I would rather spend it than preserve it.

Nonetheless, if you insist on keeping your original structure, **make it more parallel**:

> I would love to spend it rather than preserve it.

or:

> I enjoy spending it, rather than preserving it.

You can read more about parallel sentence structures at the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/).

---

Incidentally, if you are talking about money, *preserve* is not a good word to use. The word *preserve* means to keep something in its original state. I won't say it's ungrammatical, because we can dream up a scenario where it could be the right word to use:

> That's not just any dollar bill! That's a [1923 Silver Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:US-$1-SC-1923-Fr-239.jpg)! You should put that away somewhere, and keep it safe.
>
> No, thanks. **I'd rather spend it than preserve it.**

However, if you're simply talking about your weekly paycheck, I think you really want to say:

> **I would rather spend it than save it**.

(That may not be good financial advice, but it is good English advice.)

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are acceptable.

See the following link for help

http://www.perfectyourenglish.com/usage/rather-than.htm